# Camera controls not showing on device

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I went over the picker properties and examples, and set up my picker like so (using xcode 6.1, running on my device ,iphone 5s ios8):

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
```

But there crop rect/panoroma/etc controls arent showing up on my device's camera screen.

I want this:
[image]

but getting this :(

[image]

What am i missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controls you show in the first screenshot are not available with the [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isFlashAvailableForCameraDevice:) because they are part of a custom view implemented by Apple for the Camera app and are not exposed in this class.

This frees you to customize the view as you wish with the controls that you see fit for your application, and Apple recommends that you do so. If you want to do this, you should first set the [`showsCameraControls` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls) to `NO`:

> The default value of this property is YES, which specifies that the default camera controls are visible in the picker. Set it to NO to hide the default controls if you want to instead provide a custom overlay view using the cameraOverlayView property.

You can then design a custom view that utilizes the  the [`takePicture:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture) and handles output accordingly.

I'd take a look at the [class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImagePickerController/takePicture).